# Convert tab separated values to ASCII table

Tags: conversion, csv, text-formatting, ascii

What is the most efficient way to convert tab separated data such as this:

```
a   b   c   d   cat
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    d   d
NULL    NULL    c   NULL    c
NULL    NULL    c   d   c; d
NULL    b   NULL    NULL    b
NULL    b   NULL    d   b; d
NULL    b   c   NULL    b; c
NULL    b   c   d   b; c; d
a   NULL    NULL    NULL    a
a   NULL    NULL    d   a; d
a   NULL    c   NULL    a; c
a   NULL    c   d   a; c; d
a   b   NULL    NULL    a; b
a   b   NULL    d   a; b; d
a   b   c   NULL    a; b; c
a   b   c   d   a; b; c; d
```

Something close to this:

```
a    | b    | c    | d    | cat
-----+------+------+------+-----------
NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
NULL | NULL | NULL | d    | d
NULL | NULL | c    | NULL | c
NULL | NULL | c    | d    | c; d
NULL | b    | NULL | NULL | b
NULL | b    | NULL | d    | b; d
NULL | b    | c    | NULL | b; c
NULL | b    | c    | d    | b; c; d
a    | NULL | NULL | NULL | a
a    | NULL | NULL | d    | a; d
a    | NULL | c    | NULL | a; c
a    | NULL | c    | d    | a; c; d
a    | b    | NULL | NULL | a; b
a    | b    | NULL | d    | a; b; d
a    | b    | c    | NULL | a; b; c
a    | b    | c    | d    | a; b; c; d
```

Currently I use Notepad++ as follows:

1. Convert tabs to spaces
2. **Align the data manually**
3. Use column mode to insert the pipes

The second step is the most tedious one and I would rather have at least this part automated.

Note: I use a browser when working and sometimes I have a text editor open alongside. The efficient solution is the one that requires least amount of effort. I can use:

- Notepad++
- Generic text editor with regexp find/replace support
- JavaScript typed inside browser console
- Online web service
- PHP on command line (`php -a`)

Comment: What environment are you in? What tools do you have available? Which of those are you familiar with? Which ones are you willing - or unwilling - to use? How do you define "efficiency" for the purposes of this question? There are probably almost as many ways to do the job as there are people who want to do it; you need to provide additional information. See  [ask] a Good Question.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I'll update question.

Comment: It's a simple `awk` script.

Comment: @Barmar I am not using awk but I am sure  someone else will find it useful.

Comment: ask a [PCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) question about it - lulz will ensue. Wait, it's already been asked... https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100613/convert-csv-to-table (note that TSV->CSV is only a single char difference... `{{(⊃⍵)⍪⍉⍪↑¨↓⍉↑1↓⍵}s¨'⎕T'⎕T¨(s←1↓¨⊢⊂⍨⊢=⊃)¯1⌽⍵}` seems nice enough to work on, eh?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### How can I convert tab separated values to an ASCII table?

I use [Text Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for this kind of task.

I pasted your data on that page and it created the following table:

```
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | b    | c    | d    | cat        |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | NULL | NULL | d    | d          |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | NULL | c    | NULL | c          |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | NULL | c    | d    | c; d       |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | b    | NULL | NULL | b          |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | b    | NULL | d    | b; d       |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | b    | c    | NULL | b; c       |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| NULL | b    | c    | d    | b; c; d    |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | NULL | NULL | NULL | a          |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | NULL | NULL | d    | a; d       |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | NULL | c    | NULL | a; c       |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | NULL | c    | d    | a; c; d    |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | b    | NULL | NULL | a; b       |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | b    | NULL | d    | a; b; d    |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | b    | c    | NULL | a; b; c    |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
| a    | b    | c    | d    | a; b; c; d |
+------+------+------+------+------------+
```

You can then copy this output (the generator has done most of the hard work), paste into notepad++ and clean up as appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

If you need a command-line solution, you can also use [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) with the [pandoc-placetable filter](https://github.com/mb21/pandoc-placetable).

Place your table in `foo.txt` and execute:

```
pandoc-placetable --file=foo.txt --delimiter="\t" --header | pandoc -f json -t markdown-simple_tables-multiline_tables -o output.md
```

Which results in the following `output.md`:

```
| a    | b    | c    | d    | cat        |
|------|------|------|------|------------|
| NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL       |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | d    | d          |
| NULL | NULL | c    | NULL | c          |
| NULL | NULL | c    | d    | c; d       |
| NULL | b    | NULL | NULL | b          |
| NULL | b    | NULL | d    | b; d       |
| NULL | b    | c    | NULL | b; c       |
| NULL | b    | c    | d    | b; c; d    |
| a    | NULL | NULL | NULL | a          |
| a    | NULL | NULL | d    | a; d       |
| a    | NULL | c    | NULL | a; c       |
| a    | NULL | c    | d    | a; c; d    |
| a    | b    | NULL | NULL | a; b       |
| a    | b    | NULL | d    | a; b; d    |
| a    | b    | c    | NULL | a; b; c    |
| a    | b    | c    | d    | a; b; c; d |
```

To read from STDIN, leave out the `--file` argument. To print to STDOUT, leave out the `-o` argument.

Answer (score 4):

[ruslan’s idea](https://superuser.com/q/1278732/354511#1278860) of using the Unix/Linux `column` command is a good one,
but the command line given in their answer doesn’t quite work.
First of all,
`column` doesn’t recognize `\t` (or `\\t`) on the command line as a tab. 
If you have `bash`, you can do

```
column -t -s$'\t' foo.txt
```

Otherwise, you can do

```
column -t -s"$(printf '\t')" foo.txt
```

But even that doesn’t answer the question. 
You can get the vertical bars by doing

```
column -t -s$'\t' -o' | ' foo.txt
```

which produces output like

```
a    | b    | c    | d    | cat
NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL
NULL | NULL | NULL | d    | d
NULL | NULL | c    | NULL | c
NULL | NULL | c    | d    | c; d
NULL | b    | NULL | NULL | b
NULL | b    | NULL | d    | b; d
NULL | b    | c    | NULL | b; c
NULL | b    | c    | d    | b; c; d
a    | NULL | NULL | NULL | a
a    | NULL | NULL | d    | a; d
a    | NULL | c    | NULL | a; c
a    | NULL | c    | d    | a; c; d
a    | b    | NULL | NULL | a; b
a    | b    | NULL | d    | a; b; d
a    | b    | c    | NULL | a; b; c
a    | b    | c    | d    | a; b; c; d
```

Adding the dash line after the header manually isn’t so tedious.

---

If you don’t have access to a full Unix/Linux system,
you can use Cygwin or one of the other Unix-likes for this.

Comment: You didn't even comment on my answer to point out that it might not work.  I was misled by the terminal output which aligned the text due to tabs being 8 chars by default (unlike my Vim `set ts=4` setting).